# Excel VBA password protection appears broken

Tags: excel, vba

I have never seen anything like this before.  I use this code to set a password

```
Impact_Chart.Unprotect Password:="********" 

With Impact_Chart
    .Range("A19:N19").Locked = False

    .Shapes("Button 36").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 19").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 37").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 38").Locked = False
    .Protect Password:="********", Userinterfaceonly:=True
    .Protect AllowInsertingRows = True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowSorting:=True
End With
```

The problem I encounter is that after setting the password then saving the workbook is that when I came back later the password is no longer valid.  I have to use a password breaker to unprotect the sheet.

Does anyone have any information?  I've been Googling all morning and can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Further information.  Another sheet in the workbook is protected using the same password, except it is completely locked out and has been locked using the commands on the ribbon.  This sheet behaves as expected.  Any clues at all?  Cuz I am out...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it started acting strangely - I think it's because of the last two rows which are broken on to two separate lines. If you combine them then things should work correctly since I believe that once you protect a worksheet you cannot then modify the parameters of the protection.

Try the following code instead:

```
Impact_Chart.Unprotect Password:="********" 

With Impact_Chart
    .Range("A19:N19").Locked = False

    .Shapes("Button 36").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 19").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 37").Locked = False
    .Shapes("Button 38").Locked = False
    .Protect Password:="********", Userinterfaceonly:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowSorting:=True
End With
```